# httpd virtual hosts are not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost, centos6

So I recently am working on my new bootstrap website where I am using a VPS. Since I am only assigned one IP and I cannot get additional IP's, I was thinking of using Apache VirtualHosts combined with SRV records. While setting up the virtual hosts, I noticed that only virtual hosts on port 80 and 443 work. I am using ports 80, 8080, 8081, 8082 and 443. While connecting to 8080, I get a "This web page is not available" from google chrome. While connecting to 8081 and 8082, I get a "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ...". For now, I am using the domain "entel.us" because I am still transferring starfire1337.com. Here is my httpd.conf file: http://pastebin.com/awvR55aE

Any suggestions?

I am running CentOS 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your VirtualHost servernames are set to: *.starfire1337.com  but you say your using entel.us...?

Perhaps try adding:

`ServerAlias *.entel.us`  where `*` is your subdomain, i.e. `js.`

Another issue is that you have only set a `Directory` for the `/var/www/html` directory, where all your virtualhosts goto other directories in `/var/www/` so either add a `<Directory>` for each of your virtual hosts like:

```
<Directory "/var/www/js">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

or add change this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to this:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```